# Example and counter example in discrete dynamical systems

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dynamical-systems

I have some questions on Dynamical Systems.

$(X,f)$ is a Dynamical System if $f:X \to X$ is a homeomorphism and $X$ is a compact space.

$Per(f):=\{ x \in X ; f^n(x)=x , for\quad some\quad n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

$L(f):=L_{+}(f) \bigcup L_{-}(f)$ which $L_{+}(f)=\overline{\bigcup_{x\in X}\omega(x)}$ and $L_{-}(f)=\overline{\bigcup_{x\in X}\alpha(x)}$ which $\omega(x):=\{y : \exists (n_i), f^{n_i}(x) \to y \}$ and $\alpha(x):=\{y : \exists (n_i), f^{ -n_i}(x) \to y \}$

$\Omega(f)$ is the set of non wandering points, i.e. all $x$ such that $\forall$ U open containing $x$ and $\forall$ $N>0$ there exists some $n>N$ such that $f^n(U) \cap U \ne \emptyset$.

> 1 - I was looking for an example which shows that $Per(f)$ could be closed. I think I found a simple example which shows that :
> \begin{align}
> &f : [0,1] \to [0,1]\\
> &f(x)=x \quad , \forall x\in [0,1]
> \end{align}
> In this case the set $Per(f)$ is closed because we know the set of all fixed points is closed. am I right?
> Now I'm looking for an example which shows that $Per(f)$ is not closed in general, I think If we find an example whose periodic points set is empty the question will be solved.

> 2- I already proved this;
> \begin{align}
> F(f) \subseteq \overline{Per(f)} \subseteq L(f) \subseteq \Omega(f)
> \end{align}
> Now I'm looking for an example which shows that the relation may be restrict what I mean is that;
> \begin{align}
> F(f) \subset \overline{Per(f)} \subset L(f) \subset \Omega(f)
> \end{align}

> 3- The third question is also an example just like question $1,2$ I want an example which shows that;
> \begin{align}
> \overline{Per(f)} \neq \Omega(f)
> \end{align}
> For this we have to find an example which shows that;
> \begin{align}
> \Omega(f) \nsubseteq \overline{Per(f)}
> \end{align}

I consider discrete dynamical systems. Can any one help?

Comment: ad 1): not closed != open. Note that your example of $Perf(f) = [0,1]$ is clopen. Irrational rotation $x \mapsto x + \alpha \pmod{1}$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ gives a similar example of $Per(f)=\emptyset$, which is also clopen.

Comment: Do you have an example for this ?